# Enqueue multiple styles from a parent theme in a child theme in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, path, styles, parent

so this is not about the order of enqueuing a styles in a parent theme in a child theme in Wordpress. It's about the paths of the styles.

Let's say my parents theme name is simply **father** and the name of the child theme is **son**.
In my parents theme I have enqueued normalize, font-awesome and other styles.

My child theme uses the following function to enqueue styles, which works. Kind of.

```
      function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

      wp_enqueue_style( 'father-style',  get_template_directory_uri() .    '/style.css');
      wp_enqueue_style( 'son-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('father-style'), wp_get_theme()->get('Version') );
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

The problem is, Wordpress automatically changes also the paths of normalize, font-awesome, etc. to my child theme folder. I don't want that though and want the additional styles only in my parents theme. How do I do it?

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='father-style-css'  href='//localhost:3000/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/casino/style.css?ver=4.8.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='son-style-css'  href='//localhost:3000/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/son/style.css?ver=1.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />

<link rel='stylesheet' id='normailze-css' href='//localhost:3000/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/son/assets/css/normalize.css?ver=4.8.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css'  href='//localhost:3000/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/son/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.8.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
Should be father, not son -----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

Thank you.

---- Solution thanks to @Elvin85

I enqueued the styles in the parents theme with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and had to change it to `get_template_directory_uri()` to make it work as wished.

Comment: where are normalizer and font-awesome styles are enqueued? may be they are also enqueued with get_stylesheet_directory_uri() function? if so, it should be changed to get_stylesheet_directory_uri() in normalizer and font-awesome enqueues in parent theme's code

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your fast reply!
Indeed I enqueued the styles in the parents functions.php with  `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`and had to change it to `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Comment: Would be nice to see how your final `son/style.css` looks like.